# ImageView not allowed here in xml after updating android studio to 4

Tags: android

I recently updated my android studio to version 4 and suddenly a lots of bugs came up . My manifest is messed up automatically and now when i try to use an  imageview it shows that "Element ImageView is not allowed here ". I have been using android studio for 1year and never encountered such kind of problem . I am really frustrated here as this small error is wasting too much time. If anyone could help me solve this i would much appreciate it . Cheers !

also i found this in my merged manifest file

```
  (Included in merge, but did not contribute any elements) play-services-flags:16.0.1 manifest, firebase-measurement-connector:18.0.0 manifest, AndroidManifest.xml navigation file, firebase-database-collection:17.0.1 manifest, ...... etc etc
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post your xml file in which the error appears?

Comment: Any layout with parent layout relative , linear etc.... There is no error in code it just shows element not allowed. Even if I create a new layout , i can't just place a imageview

Comment: I deleted and installed again the android sdk still the same shit